# Possible to setup a secondary email server with unique addresses?

Tags: email, email-server, microsoft-office-365, email-bounces

It is possible to setup two email gateways such that if a record doesn't match the first server then it attempts a second server before failing to deliver?

**Background:** Client recently switched from in-house servers to Office 365. There was an email account setup before as a catch-all for web related matters (account configurations, password recovery, etc).

Since they are now on Office 365, they are saying that each email account costs money and are reluctant to create a full Office 365 account just for an email account.

I'm thinking rather than creating an Office account, maybe I can use a service such as Google Apps just for generic email addresses.

Unfortunately, I don't know off-hand how to configure domain records to try a secondary email server if the primary fails to deliver.

Comment: You can't do this using the MX records as a mechanism, but you could do this using an SMTP shared namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for any zone (a.k.a. mail domain), there is a single set of authoritative servers, as designated by the MX records for that zone. If the mailbox does not exist on those servers, an NDR will be generated and sent back to the sending party.

Comment: thank you for the direct answer, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @EEAA Technically, this isn't correct. You could configure the domain in Office 365 as an internal relay, and then configure a Send connector for some other mail server.  On receipt of email, Exchange will check O365 for recipient first, if it doesn't exist, then it'll pass the message to the Send connector.